# vitepress env variables in markdown files

Tags: vite, vitepress

I'd like to retrieve the git build and branch data from an environment variable I can set/export at build time.
is there a way I can reference such an env variable somewhere in the markdown files or config files? tia!

Comment: did you figure it out?